# Python Class and Object Parameters

Tags: python, string, class, object, doc

just a quick regarding classes and objects.

I have created a python file called Arm, which contains a class as shown below:-

```
class HelloClass:
    """
    This is the doc string
    """
    
    def __init__(self, A= "",B = "", C = "", D = ""):
        
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D

        print("Object Created")
```

In the same directory i have created a new python called test and imported the class using the following code:-

```
import Arm

london = Arm.HelloClass()

london.A = 23
```

The issue is that when i enter the line of code `london = Arm.HelloClass(` i would normally get a dialogue box to show me all of the parameters i.e. `london = Arm.HelloClass(A= "",B = "", C = "", D = "")` but this does not show up in the test file - does anyone know why?

Also when i create an object and try to set one of the attributes python does not auto fill the rest of the attribute i was wondering if anyone knew why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it runs as expected. I don't get a popup. I just get console output as expected.

I used this code to test you Arm module:

```
import Arm

london = Arm.HelloClass()
london.A = 23
print(london.__dict__)
```

Output

```
Object Created
{'A': 23, 'B': '', 'C': '', 'D': ''}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, the thing is that i want to get the pop up so that i can see what arguments the object wants to take.  When i enter ondon = Arm.HelloClass( but dont close the brackets my IDE spyder brings up the list of arguments the object is expecting - i hope this makes sense.